# How do you map a group-algebra into another algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group with elements **1, -1** with the obvious group multiplication rules, I can create a group-algebra $\mathbb{R}[\mathbf{1},\mathbf{-1}]$. But this is a $2$ dimensional $\mathbb R$  algebra. What I would like is to map this algebra back into the real numbers.

Similarly given a group with elements **1,-1, i, -i**. The group-algebra created from this is 4 dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, whereas I want to map this into the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ or a pair of real numbers $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Another example is the group $\mathbb{Z}_3$ with elements **1**,  $\omega$, $\omega^2$. The group algebra is $3$ dimensional over $\mathbb R$, but again I would like to map this onto the algebra of complex numbers with $\omega\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{-3})$.

How do we express this mapping? In the first case it's because we want an equivalence between $a\mathbf{1}+b(\mathbf{-1})$ and $(a+c)\mathbf{1}+(b+c)(\mathbf{-1})$. So would we have to divide the algebra somehow by this equivalence? But still make sure we have a valid algebra.

Comment: I corrected a number of typos in your post: let me know if I changed anything you did not intend.

Comment: If you write the group elements in brackets, then e.g. $\Bbb R[\Bbb Z_3]\to\Bbb C$ would be $$ a[1]+b[\omega]+c[\omega^2]\mapsto a+b\omega+c\omega^2 $$

Comment: Yes, I guess this is pretty straight forward. If for each group element $g$ the mapping $f$ is such that $f(g_1) \times_{\mathbb{C}} f(g_2) = f(g_1 \times_G g_2)$. Where the first case is the multiplication for complex numbers and the second case is the group multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything interesting about the group algebra itself that complicates things. You can determine what isomorphisms are possible by analyzing the structure.  They are all commutative semsimple algebras over $\mathbb R$, so they can only be made up of blocks of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$.

$\mathbb R[\{\pm 1\}]\cong\mathbb R^2$ which has four ideals, two of which allow mapping back onto $\mathbb R$.  The most attractive is probably the augmentation mapping $\sum k_gg\mapsto \sum k_g$. You will have this for every group algebra over $\mathbb R$, by the way.

$\mathbb R[\{\pm 1, \pm i\}]\cong \mathbb R[x]/(x^4-1)\cong\mathbb C\times\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ has $8$ ideals, one allowing a mapping back onto $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$, and one allowing a map back onto $\mathbb C$, and two allowing mappings back onto $\mathbb R$.

$\mathbb R[\{1,\omega,\omega^2\}]\cong\mathbb R[x]/(x^3-1) \cong \mathbb C \times \mathbb R$, so it admits one homomorphism onto $\mathbb C$ by modding out by the ideal generated by $1+\omega+\omega^2$ when you use precisely the map you described ($\omega$ mapping to a third root of unity in $\mathbb C$.)

> Well what I would say is interesting about the group-algebra, is that you can take certain elements from ℝ such as 1 and -1 and form a group. Then the idea is to get back to the algebra you started with.

Of course, if you picked a subgroup $H$ of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb C$, there would be a unique $\mathbb R$-algebra homomorphism of $\mathbb R[H]\to \mathbb C$. That's guaranteed by the universal property of the group ring. For the cyclic group of order $n>2$, this is always going to produce a mapping back onto $\mathbb C$, because the image contains something on the real axis (namely $1$) and something complex (one of the complex roots of $x^n-1$) so that its image has $\mathbb R$ dimension $2$.

Comment: Well what I would say is interesting about the group-algebra, is that you can take certain elements from $\mathbb{R}$ such as 1 and -1 and form a group. Then the idea is to get back to the algebra you started with.

Comment: So you can always divide a group-algebra by it's augmentation mapping?

Comment: @zooby The augmentation ideal is defined for any group algebra... In the case $G$ is a finite group $\mathbb R$ always splits off of $\mathbb R[G]$, and so it's also a quotient.

Comment: So I might say  $\mathbf{H}\subset \mathbb{C}^\times \implies \exists f |f:\mathbb{R}[\mathbf{H}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ (I like using set theory notation!)

Comment: @zooby Yes, it is true that $\mathbb R[H]$ will always map *into* $\mathbb C$ with an $\mathbb R$ algebra homomorphism for $H< \mathbb C^\times$. Such a homomorphism would either be onto $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb C$ or onto $\mathbb C$ depending on the dimension of the image of the homomorphism.

Comment: For cyclic groups, since $x^n-1$ always has a complex root for $n>2$, the image will be onto $\mathbb C$ if you're mapping that group element back where it came from (another dimension will lie entirely in $\mathbb R$, of course.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim No, the silly error is mine:  somehow I was convinced originally that the user had written a representation of the Klein 4 group. That's why I alsy wrote the thing about it not being a subgroup of $\mathbb C^\times$ But of course that isn’t the case... I’ll make that consistent shortly.

Comment: @AlexWertheim There, should be good now. Thanks for alerting me.

Comment: @rschwieb: thanks, looks good! +1